# Understanding file i/o with while loops

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

The output to the console of this program is as intended, however the output written to the text file does not reflect this. I'm fairly sure this is because of the increment of y(++) but I'm not sure how to solve the problem without messing with the logic flow and my attempts so far have been less than successful. I've been working on this for a while so if you've seen me around before do excuse my slow progress, I'm learning as I go!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAX_STR_LEN 120

int main(){

char *cArray[MAX_STR_LEN] = { "example", "dinosaurs" };
char cInput[MAX_STR_LEN] = { 0 };
int y = 0;
FILE *pWrite;

printf("Type your message:\n");
fgets(cInput, MAX_STR_LEN, stdin);
cInput[strlen(cInput) - 1] = 0;     /* strip newline from input */
printf("\nInitialised string array:\n");

time_t rawtime;
struct tm * timeinfo;

time ( &rawtime );
timeinfo = localtime ( &rawtime );

while (cArray[y]){
    char * ptr = cInput;
    while ((ptr = strstr(ptr, cArray[y])) != NULL){
        char *ep = strchr (ptr, ' ');
        if (ep) *ep = 0;              /* null-terminate at space */
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
        if (ep) *ep = ' ';            /* put the space back      */

        pWrite = fopen("test.txt", "a");
        if ( pWrite != NULL ) {
            fprintf(pWrite, "%s\n", ptr++);
            fprintf(pWrite, "%s\n", asctime (timeinfo));
            fclose(pWrite);
        } else {
            goto ErrorHandler; //there is a file i/o error
        }
    }
    y++;
    }
printf ( "Timestamp: %s", asctime (timeinfo) );

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); //exit program normally

ErrorHandler:
perror("The following error occurred");
exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //exit program with error
}
```

Console Output:

```
Type your message:
this is an example of dinosaurs
Initialised string array:
example
dinosaurs
Timestamp: Sat Mar  7 16:04:42 2015
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

File Output:

```
example of dinosaurs
Sat Mar  7 16:04:42 2015

dinosaurs
Sat Mar  7 16:04:42 2015
```

Expected File Output:

```
Initialised string array:
example
dinosaurs
Timestamp: Sat Mar  7 16:04:42 2015
```

Comment: Ok, so the output the file is not what you intended it to be. But what was your intension? You have shown the result, and you have shown the code (which, unsurprisingly, does exactly what it says it does), but you haven't said what it was that you expected to happen.

Comment: Show us the expected file output

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, cArray[y] is never NULL.. it is "example", "dinosaurs", and then undefined.   So the outer while loop could go on for quite a while. I think you want to explicitly define

```
char *cArray[] = { "example","dinosaurs",NULL };
```

This guarantees that the outer while loop will terminate.  But the real problem you're asking about is actually not as bad as you think.

First, you explicitly added a null terminator to the string before you printf to the console, but then you remove it again BEFORE you write to the file:

truncate the sting to a single word:

```
    char *ep = strchr (ptr, ' ');
    if (ep) *ep = 0;              /* null-terminate at space */
```

print it

```
    printf("%s\n", ptr);
    if (ep) *ep = ' ';            /* put the space back      */
```

Now its the full string again when we write to the file:

```
    pWrite = fopen("test.txt", "a");
    if ( pWrite != NULL ) {
        fprintf(pWrite, "%s\n", ptr++);
        fprintf(pWrite, "%s\n", asctime (timeinfo));
        fclose(pWrite);
```

so you see the full remainder of the string when you write it to the file "example of dinosaur".  Then the second time through, you see dinosaur like you're supposed to, because it happens to be the last word of the string.

Next, you print out the date stamp every time through the inner loop.. that why the date stamp shows up twice.  Also, you never write your "Initialized string array" string to the file at all (only with printf, not fprintf).

Hope that helps.

Comment: This has been a fantastic help, thank you so much. I've figured out the kinks and it works perfectly now! No doubt I'll be back when I want to add some more but for now this is all I need so thank you again!